# Probabilistically Selecting A Set Number of Items Over Time

Tags: java, math, probability

I have an enterprise application running on a server that accepts files. Tens of thousands of files are submitted every day by users. The customer wants exactly 50 of these files to be automatically selected for audit each day.

The requirements are:

1. the files must be selected as they come in (we can't wait for all the files to come in and then choose 50 at the end of the day)
2. the files selected must meet some other criteria, which they haven't told me yet, but I am assured there will still be thousands of files that meet these criteria
3. the system must not be "game-able". That is - they don't want users who submit files to realise that if they wait until the afternoon or something, their files never get audited. This means we can't just choose the first 50 that come in, the selected files must be randomly spread out throughout the day.
4. we have to have EXACTLY 50 files. Or so they say. But I'm pretty sure if it just so happened that no user submitted a file that matched the criteria after midday one day, and we only got 25 files, they'd be ok with that. So I can assume that the types of files I'm interested in are submitted with a reasonably regular frequency throughout the day.

I figure then, that I need some function that calculates a probability that a file will be selected, that uses the number of currently chosen files and the time of day as inputs.

I've created a test harness. Please forgive the dodgy code. In this, the "pushTask" thread simulates files coming in by adding them to a stack. "Files" in this test are just Strings with a random number on the end.

The "pullTask" thread simulates files being pulled off the stack. It asks requirementsFunction() if the "file" meets the extra requirements needed (and in this test that's just - does it end in a zero), and it asks probabilityFunction() if it should select the file. If a file is selected, it is printed to System.out.

Really I need some help as to what to put in probabilityFunction(), because at the moment what's in there is garbage (I've left it in so you can see what I've tried). Or if someone knows of a mathematical probability function that uses items/time that would be great too.

```
package com.playground;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Random;

public class ProbabilisticSelection {

    private static int TOTAL_FILES = 1000;
    private static int AUDIT_QUANTITY = 10;
    private static int TIME_IN_SECONDS_FOR_ALL_FILES = 10;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<String>();
    private boolean finished;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new ProbabilisticSelection().test();
    }

    private void test() throws InterruptedException {
        Instant begin = Instant.now();

        Runnable pushTask = () -> {
            while (!finished) {
                int next = random.nextInt(TOTAL_FILES);
                String item = "File: " + next;
                stack.push(item);
                if (Duration.between(begin, Instant.now()).getSeconds() >= TIME_IN_SECONDS_FOR_ALL_FILES) {
                    finished = true;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable pullTask = () -> {
            int itemNumber = 1;
            while (itemNumber <= AUDIT_QUANTITY && !finished) {
                String poll = stack.poll();
                if (requirementsFunction(poll) &&
                        probabilityFunction(itemNumber, Duration.between(begin, Instant.now()))) {
                    System.out.println(itemNumber++ + ": "+ poll);
                } 
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            finished = true;
            Duration delta = Duration.between(begin, Instant.now());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Retrieved files: " + (itemNumber - 1) + ", should be, " + AUDIT_QUANTITY);
            System.out.println("Time taken: " + delta.getSeconds() + ", should be, " + TIME_IN_SECONDS_FOR_ALL_FILES);
        };

        new Thread(pullTask).start();
        new Thread(pushTask).start();
    }

    private boolean requirementsFunction(String item) {
        return item != null && item.endsWith("0");
    }

    private boolean probabilityFunction(int itemNumber, Duration delta) {
        double limit = ((double)(AUDIT_QUANTITY-itemNumber)/(double)AUDIT_QUANTITY + 1); // probability goes down as number of items goes up
        double tension = (double)TIME_IN_SECONDS_FOR_ALL_FILES/((double)delta.getSeconds() + 1); // probablity goes up as time nears the end
        if (tension == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        double prob = limit * tension * 100; 
        int rand = random.nextInt(1000);
        return prob > rand;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know going down this route sounds like an absolute pain, but would it be possible to use an approximated function for the submission distribution from actual data recorded from your app over some time period? Then feed this distribution into the selection criteria. [The Poisson point process may be of help.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Non-homogeneous)

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm is called [Reservoir_sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling), which guarantees fair sampling of `k` items from some large and unknown `N`. Hereis Java [code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reservoir-sampling/)

Comment: Unfortunately for me I cannot "deselect" a file once it has been "selected". It seems that reservoir sampling fills the "reservoir" and then replaces an item with some probability so that the reservoir is always full. I can't do that.

Comment: @PhilBarr Then what you want is impossible. With reservoir sampling, probability of single item is 1/N, whatever N is, even if you don't know it upfront. If you cannot remove item(s), then first ones selected will have by definition higher probability, whatever algorithm you deploy - they are selected from first K items, K < N, and at  best you could make probability 1/K > 1/N. You just don't have information at that point to make probability of selection 1/N. Reservoir sampling beauty is in probability adjustment on-the-fly, effectively for all items in the pool.